# Area of the set of all points such that they are in the center area

Tags: integration, geometry

On the XY Plane we place a square with side length 1.
A point is **in the center area** if the distance from it to the center of the square is smaller than the distance from it to every side of the square.
Find the area of the set of all points that are in the center area.

I think integrals are needed in this type of problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Since the parabola is the locus of the points with the same distance from a given point (focus)  and from a 
given line (directrix), then for each side we have a parabola, whose focus is the center and whose directrix
is the side and vertex at the midpoint of the normal to the side through the center.
Due to symmetry, the central area you are looking for is made by the four sectors, 
each resulting from the diagonals and the parabolic arcs that they intercepts.

Comment: I can't really see how to continue, could you please tell me how to solve it? BTW I need it for tommorow :( thanks

Comment: This website is not for us to do your homework for you.

Comment: never asked you to do my homework, I asked you to help, and right now your'e not helping.

Comment: False.  You wrote:  "BTW I need it for tommorow."  And if you can't see that the work I did to create the figure you couldn't make for yourself is "not helping,..." well I suspect you're going to get very little assistance on this site.

Answer (score 2):

More hint:

@GCab sets you in the right direction.  Perhaps this figure will help:

[image]

Comment: thanks! I see it now.

Comment: good, that's the right complement to my answer.